# How to find point within polygon with in TURF

Tags: turf

I want to find point within polygon with TURF, but it doesn't work.

My point is geoJSON format (*.geojson)
My polygon is geoJSON format, too (*.js)

This is my code:

```
var ranh_gioi_JS;
var ghi_chu_dan_cu;
ranh_gioi_JS = L.geoJSON(RG);
ghi_chu_dan_cu = L.geoJson(ghi_chu_dan_cu);
var ptsWithin = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(ghi_chu_dan_cu, ranh_gioi_JS);
```

This is my point format:

```
    var ghi_chu_dan_cu = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "ghi_chu_dan_cu",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 1, "Layer": "L�ng K�in", "Content": "L�ng K�in" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 107.54879, 14.37848 ] } },
]
}
```

This is my polygon format:

```
var RG = {"type":"FeatureCollection","name":"RG_0","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},"features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"OBJECTID":"1","LEFT_FID":"102","RIGHT_FID":"96","Shape_Leng":17608.111100099999,"created_us":null,"created_da":null,"last_edite":null,"last_edi_1":null},"geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[107.445124268815249,13.996292582285076],[107.44558019849498,13.996433086876252],[107.445649455366663,13.996686987229884],[107.44581702184496,13.997319085537034],[107.445917183401548,13.997660165829029],[107.446199851154461,13.998406326453489],[107.446909041599866,13.999427663231261],[107.447641489721562,14.000482300023167],[107.448113133274759,14.001774332914872],[107.44828512754583,14.002879344167436],[107.448290026946452,14.004422034524103],[107.448222448664112,14.005607720655911],[107.448151909736723,14.006513955571853],[107.448094003059481,14.007531854496913],[107.448051217182268,14.008896158231833],[107.448166336908102,14.010035280948937],[107.448267058345394,14.011426441863177],}}]}
```